# Как в groovy лучше всего проверить импортировался ли класс?

Tags: groovy, soapui

в groovy импортирую свой клас например `import com.orwell.lib.Logger` который находится в jarнике.
Как можно проверить импортировался ли класс? и существует ли он вообще в jarнике

Answer (score -1):

Jar'ник это всего лишь архив, вы можете открыть его и проверить наличие данного класса.
Если скрипт скомпилировался без проблем - значит импорт удался

Comment: Мне нужно программно узнать что import библиотеки завершился корректно.

Comment: Значит я не правильно понял вопрос. Можно получить класс через класс лоадер `java.lang.Class#forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader)` или `java.lang.Class#forName(java.lang.String)`. Он как раз выкидывает исключение(ClassNotFoundException), если класс не обнаружен